# Rounding off error yields weird subsetting result in R

Tags: r, subset

I am trying to split a vector in half (and get the second half)

Why is this not working? When evaluating all the single parts on their own, they yield the right results, but the actual result is not what I expected:

```
data <- 1:11    
> length(data)
[1] 11
> ((length(data) / 2)+1)
[1] 6.5
> data[((length(data) / 2)+1):length(data)]  # same as: data[6.5:11]
[1]  6  7  8  9 10
```

While I expected:

```
[1] 6 7 8 9 10 11
```

I guess `floor` is a solution, but this still confuses me: it would either start from 6 or 7, but at least continue to 11, yet it doesn't?

Answer (score 2):

Did you check what `((length(data) / 2)+1):length(data)` actually is?

```
> data <- 1:11  
> ((length(data) / 2)+1):length(data)
[1]  6.5  7.5  8.5  9.5 10.5
```